# Обработка формы

Tags: php

Есть форма

```
<form action="test.php" method="post">
    name<input type="text" name="nemus"><br/>
    family<input type="text" name="famel"><br/>
    <input type="submit">
</form>
```

И есть файл test.php со скриптом, который ее должен обрабатывать

```
<? echo"Поздравляем $nemus $famel вы выиграли авто!";?>
```

Но в сообщении test.php при обработке появляется только текст, сами переменные не обрабатываются.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Быть может, потому что не привязаны переменные `$nemus` и `$famel` к аналогичным элементам из массива `$_POST`? С выключенным `register_globals` ))

```
$name = (isset($_POST['name']))?htmlspecialchars($_POST['name']):"";
```

Comment: а как привязать?

Comment: Ну, к примеру, так: `$nemus = $_POST['nemus'];`  перед выводом echo, понятное дело.

Не забываем еще про фильтрацию от возможных атак. )))

Comment: Если версия php > 5.2, то можно таким образом: 

    $str = filter_var($str, FILTER_SANITIZE_SPECIAL_CHARS); 

или стандартным `htmlspecialchars();`